# Saving Visualforce page as a PDF including Temporary Controller Variables

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I have a page I am working on that grabs data using an account ID. It allows the user to edit the data and then highlight some parts of the data. The edited data is saved to their account and a PDF is returned showing the highlighting. The highlighting is not saved since it only matters on this one run.

The issue I have is that I am getting a network error when 'downloading' the PDF (in Chrome). I added a line in the page header for 'contentType="application/x-pdf#DocName.pdf"' and it now only saves as a 'Chrome HTML Document' but at least the network error is gone. When I go directly to the PDF (with the currently saved data, but no temporary instances of highlighting) and download, it works correctly and saves as a PDF. So for some reason, I just can't save a PDF version of the document with the temporary highlighting. I don't want to save the highlighting anywhere to Salesforce and I would prefer to show the PDF before letting the user choose whether or not to 'download'/save. Is there another way around this that I am just missing?

Here is the apex:page line in my PDF page and the new pagereference that I return after saving the permanent changes in the controller. Please let me know if any other lines would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" controller="MyController" renderAs="PDF" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" standardStylesheets="false" contentType="application/x-pdf#DocName.pdf">

return new PageReference('/apex/DocNamePDF?id=' + accountdId);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I've fully understood, but you could possibly use a dataUri for this, something like this:

**Controller**

```
public PDFController
{
    private Id accountId;
    public PDFController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        accountId = controller.getId();
    }
    public String getContent()
    {            
        PageReference ref = return new PageReference('/apex/DocNamePDF?id=' + accountdId);
        Blob contentData = ref.getContentAsPDF();
        return 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(contentData);
    }
}
```

**Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" showHeader="true" sidebar="true" extensions="PDFController">

    <apex:iframe height="500px" width="1000px" src="{!content}">
    </apex:iframe>

</apex:page>
```

I've used a similar approach before for previewing PDFs, rendering the PDF in an iFrame should allow you to use the PDF plugin save button.

Comment: This did the trick! I had to adjust a couple things to make it work for my situation.

<apex:page controller="MyController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">

In the controller, instead of a new page reference, I did the getContentAsPDF before returning the page so it remembered my variables:
PageReference ref = new PageReference('/apex/DocNamePDF?id=' + accountId);
        Blob contentData = ref.getContentAsPDF();
        pageRefPDF = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(contentData);
        return new PageReference('/apex/DisplayPDF?id=' + accountId);

Comment: Good stuff, glad I could help!